# what coding format and standard should be followed while writing javascript library

Tags: javascript

I am working to build my own custom UI library providing a feature like customized form elements, cards, tabular view and much more, most of the feature is inherited from bootstrap. there is a lot of javascript code and I am looking for proper standard and format to be followed while writing any javascript library to make the code manageable and can be reused.

Comment: Over SO, we do not **recommend**. Project structure and management ways will differ from person to person. My suggestion, look 2-3 libraries, how they are structured and evaluate their pros and cons and adapt one that suits you

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm - the only one which you MUST follow.

Comment: my basic need is to share the common events , some common set of selectors and some effects . i had refereed bootstrap they are using prototypes widely.

Comment: finally i found usefull link for this problem http://www.mikedoesweb.com/2012/creating-your-own-javascript-library/